# Get POST data in C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get POST data, but I'm having no luck. My code is below. When I click the form button nothing happens.

I expected at least my IDE to snap at `A.Ret()`, but nothing happens whatsoever.

#### File Test.cs

```
using System.Web;
public class A
{
    public static string ret() {
        var c = HttpContext.Current;
        var v = c.Request.QueryString; // <-- I can see get data in this
        return c.Request.UserAgent.ToString();
        return c.Request.UserHostAddress.ToString();
        return "woot";
    }
}
```

#### File Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="aspnetCSone._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" action="Default.aspx">
            <input type=hidden name="AP" value="99" />
            <input type=button value="Submit" />
            <div>
                <a id="aa">a</a>
                <% = A.ret() %>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... Where are you trying to get POST data?

Comment: This code makes no sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Don't try to get POST data, mark the control as runat="server" and then get the value that way.

Comment: rball: How do i get the value 'that' way? I am an utter newbie. Blixt: The form should be POSTing the data when i click submit. Like how it does in PHP and all HTML code i have done before today.

Answer (score 43):

Try using:

```
string ap = c.Request["AP"];
```

That reads from the cookies, form, query string or server variables.

Alternatively:

```
string ap = c.Request.Form["AP"];
```

to just read from the form's data.

Answer (score 32):

`c.Request["AP"]` will read posted values. Also you need to use a submit button to post the form:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

instead of

```
<input type=button value="Submit" />
```

Comment: I realize this is way old, but it helped me too... though I was using VB... 'Dim sku As String = Request("sku")'... thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm a little surprised that this question has been asked so many times before, but the most reuseable and friendly solution hasn't been documented.

I often have webpages using AngularJS, and when I click on a Save button, I'll "POST" this data back to my .aspx page or .ashx handler to save this back to the database.  The data will be in the form of a JSON record.

On the server, to turn the raw posted data back into a C# class, here's what I would do.

First, define a C# class which will contain the posted data.

Supposing my webpage is posting JSON data like this:

```
{
    "UserID" : 1,
    "FirstName" : "Mike",
    "LastName" : "Mike",
    "Address1" : "10 Really Street",
    "Address2" : "London"
}
```

Then I'd define a C# class like this...

```
public class JSONRequest
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
}
```

(These classes can be nested, but the structure must match the format of the JSON data.  So, if you're posting a JSON User record, with a list of Order records within it, your C# class should also contain a `List<>` of Order records.)

Now, in my .aspx.cs or .ashx file, I just need to do this, and leave JSON.Net to do the hard work...

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string jsonString = "";
        HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        using (StreamReader inputStream = new StreamReader(this.Request.InputStream))
        {
            jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
        JSONRequest oneQuestion = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONRequest>(jsonString);
```

And that's it.  You now have a `JSONRequest` class containing the various fields which were POSTed to your server.

Answer (score 1):

The following is OK in HTML4, but not in XHTML. Check your editor.

```
<input type=button value="Submit" />
```