# unable to pass post value over from ajax to the page in .net c#

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, web-applications

Does anyone know what is it going on here? I have try to pass a value from ajax to .aspx, but somehow the value seem doesn't pass over successfully.

Following is my code:

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "pgtest.aspx",
      data: "sState=VIC",
      success: function (msg) {
          alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
      }
  });
```

and this is my code inside my .net c#:

```
newTest.Value = Request.QueryString["sState"];
```

Somehow the for Request.QueryString["sState"] is empty in .net c#. Does anyone know what is going wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing data in POST, the data is not passed in `Request.QueryString`, it's passed into `Request.Form` instead. Try

```
newTest.Value = Request.Form["sState"];
```

Another thing I'd change is the jQuery call - use a data object instead of just a string, a such:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "pgtest.aspx",
      data: { sState: "VIC" },
      success: function (msg) {
          alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Request.QueryString` is for GET requests only. For POST requests, you need `Request.Form`. See also: [Get POST data in C#/ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976613/get-post-data-in-c-asp-net)

Comment: When you use the `Request` indexer (`Request[...]`), you can get values from either `QueryString`, `Form`, `Cookies` or `ServerVariables`. If you know which one the value should be in - and you should always be able to know - use that. In this case, like I mentioned in my answer, it's `Form`.

Comment: I'll admit it - I forgot :) I don't use ASP.NET much. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GET request as it is light in nature but less secured too and it is passed in querystring.:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "pgtest.aspx?sState=VIC",      
      success: function (msg) {
          alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
      }
  });
```

Now you will get below values:

```
newTest.Value = Request.QueryString["sState"];
```