# Why I get null values in post ajax call?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

Here is my JavaScript block:

```
  <script>
    var u;
    var p;

    function login() {
        u = $("#userNameID").val();
        p = $("#passwordID").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Login.aspx",
            data: { username: u, password: p},
            success: function () { alert("success!!!") }
        });
    }
</script>
```

At server side after the post call I try to retrive values this way:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string user = Request.QueryString["username"];
        string pswrd = Request.QueryString["password"];
    }
```

But both values are null.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this two solution you might get your Answer:

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972789/unable-to-pass-post-value-over-from-ajax-to-the-page-in-net-c-sharp)

[Solution 2](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-Pass-Data-Values-from-one-page-to-another-using-jQuery.aspx)