# Persist Facebook Access Token

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am running asp.net application on Facebook,which has multiple pages.
On landing page I obtain access token.
Question is how to persist that access token so that I can use it in other pages
to access current user data.
Current when I try following in other pages,

```
Facebook.FacebookAPI fbApi = new Facebook.FacebookAPI();
JSONObject currentUser = fbApi.Get("/me");
```

it breaks saying unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

You should just store the access token in your database along with a user ID reference. Alternatively you can just use a client side SDK like the Facebook [Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) which will persist for you without having to go extra effort.

Comment: considering that application will be used concurrently by many users. how to store current User id for current session Note:i cannot use sessions  as i am using windows azure. so any other way?

Comment: If you have built an app on Facebook.com, then every time that a user accesses your app, it will be sent a [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) which can be decoded to receive a user ID (which could be matched to the access token stored in your DB) as well as the oauth_token which is the same as the access_token. You should use this.

Comment: great help.. how to get the signed request in c# ?

Comment: The signed_request is POSTed to any URL loaded in a Facebook app, so you just need to use the C# methods for retrieving POST requests. Here is a previous StackOverflow question which deals with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976613/get-post-data-in-c-asp-net

Comment: i cant get signed_request in post data any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're using the most recent version of the API.  It looks like you're using the deprecated one from https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk#readme

If you're using the latest one, then you can persist the access token. Grab the latest from: 
https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/#readme