# how to display the embedded code value in the HTML hidden input

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have this hidden input from HTML, which contain the value of the total number and display out once save is click.
Like this:

`<input id="hidden" runat="server" type="text" value="<% hidden %>" />`

`<asp:Button ID="save" runat="server" Text="Save" class="bottom" />`

Behind of asp.page

`Protected Sub save_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles save.Click`

`Dim str As String = Request.Form("hidden")`

`Response.Write(str)`

`End Sub`

But it could not display the hidden value I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `name="hidden"` in the input tag.

```
<input id="hidden" runat="server" type="text" name="hidden" value="<% hidden %>" />
```

See this question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/976682/2671135