# Build my Html.Partial string in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, partial-views

I have a javascript function that accepts arguments including the page name to load. I want to be able to build out the call to Html.Partial based on this information.  What I'm trying to do is this:

```
function tabs_itemClick(e) {
   alert("my path should be [" + e.itemData.Path + "]";
   var url = '_' + e.itemData.Path;
   @{Html.Partial(url, new ActivityLog());
}
```

Obviously this fails because the variable url does not exist for the @{Html.Partial}.  How do you get around this?

Comment: You can't mix C# and JS like this, unless you expect the C# to run completely before the JS does.

Comment: Then is there any way to pass in the name of the partial page to Html.Partial?

Comment: Expose an action method and then use ajax to post to it and have it return a partial. Or switch to blazor

Comment: A couple questions which might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576047/how-to-pass-javascript-variable-to-server-side-asp-net https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639278/pass-javascript-variable-to-codebehind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what you really want is **to render a HTML code segment base on a javascript variable.**

What you need to do is setting up another action in your controller to accept ajax calls from the frontend.

Define a action accepting the name of partial view in the controller:

```
[HttpGet("/api/employee-login")]
public ActionResult EmployeeLogin(string partialViewName)  
{
    return PartialView(partialViewName , new ActivityLog());
}
```

After that, create a partial view and place it under the corresponding directory.

In your frontend, you should fire a GET ajax call with your partial view name e.g.

```
var myViewName = "_" + e.itemData.Path;
$.get("/api/employee-login", { partialViewName: myViewName,} )
  .done(function( data ) {
    /* inject the HTML segment returned into your document */
  });
/* you may also need some code to handle some situations e.g. view not found */
```

For example, if `e.itemData.Path` = "_myView", then you need to have a partial view named `_myView.cshtml` defined in your project.

Comment: Thanks! That looks promising, but I also have a different model to pass into the partial view based on link path as well.  How would I do that?

Comment: I am not sure what will be the content of your model so I assume you want to pass a json object first. In this case you can change the GET call into POST call, and passing the json object as the ajax data. On C# side you need to define a binding model and put it as the param of the action